# how to change the color of multiple days using wpcontrols:calendar

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

Hi I am new to windows Phone. I am working on an application in which there is a calendar with multiple events which comes from database (dyanmic). For calendar I am using wpcontrols:calendar and to change the background color of the event I am using ColorConvertor. I am able to change the background color of a single day but unable to change the color of more a day. The requirement is events may vary at any point of time. Below is my code :

XAML Code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="cal.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:wpControls="clr-namespace:WPControls;assembly=WPControls"
xmlns:WpControlsExample="clr-namespace:cal"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <WpControlsExample:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <wpControls:Calendar 
            x:Name="Cal"
            ColorConverter="{StaticResource ColorConverter}"
            MonthChanged="Cal_MonthChanged"
            MonthChanging="Cal_MonthChanging"
            SelectionChanged="Cal_SelectionChanged"
            DateClicked="Cal_DateClicked"
            EnableGestures="True"
            />
        <!--<wpControls:Calendar 
            x:Name="Cal"/>-->
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=Cal, Path=SelectedDate}"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

CS code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using cal.Resources;
using System.Windows.Media;
using WPControls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace cal
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Cal.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;

        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Cal_MonthChanged(object sender, WPControls.MonthChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cal_MonthChanged fired.  New year is " + e.Year.ToString() + " new month is " + e.Month.ToString());

        }

        private void Cal_MonthChanging(object sender, WPControls.MonthChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cal_MonthChanging fired.  New year is " + e.Year.ToString() + " new month is " + e.Month.ToString());
        }

        private void Cal_SelectionChanged(object sender, WPControls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cal_SelectionChanged fired.  New date is " + e.SelectedDate.ToString());
        }

        private void Cal_DateClicked(object sender, WPControls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cal_DateClicked fired.  New date is " + e.SelectedDate.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

CS Code for ColorConverter.cs :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;
using WPControls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace cal
{
    public class ColorConverter : IDateToBrushConverter
        {
            public Brush Convert(DateTime dateTime, bool isSelected, Brush defaultValue, BrushType brushType)
                {
                    String MyString;
                    MyString = "2013-09-01 21:34 PM";
                    DateTime MyDateTime;
                    MyDateTime = new DateTime();
                    MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",null);
                    if (brushType == BrushType.Background)
                        {
                            if (dateTime == new DateTime(MyDateTime.Year, MyDateTime.Month, MyDateTime.Day))
                                {

                                    // Fill rectangle with an ImageBrush
                                    //blueRectangle.Fill = imgBrush;
                                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    return defaultValue;
                                }
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            if (dateTime == new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 6))
                                {
                                     return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    return defaultValue;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Please help me out...
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your converter.  You are only changing a color of a single day bsed on the comparison if (dateTime == new DateTime(MyDateTime.Year, MyDateTime.Month, MyDateTime.Day))

If you change this code for example to the following, all Sundays will change to yellow.  Does this answer your question?
Thanks

Sergey

```
    public Brush Convert(DateTime dateTime, bool isSelected, Brush defaultValue, BrushType brushType)
    {
        if (brushType == BrushType.Background)
        {
            if (dateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            }
            return defaultValue;
        }
        if (dateTime == new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 6))
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
```

Comment: But it is not only that about any particular day of a week. The date I will be getting from database, so it may be on any day, any month, any year. please check this and help me.. Thanx for responding...

Comment: Not exactly, It is not what m I luking for... Above snippet will change the color of all the Sundays. But my requirement is to change the background color of multiple days which comes from local database. It is not based on any particular day or date. Well let me be more clear, I feel the IF condition must be dynamic with OR operators. Like If(dateTime == obj1 || dateTime == obj2 || --- || n){return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);}. But I am not getting how to make this condition dynamic? If I get this solution then It will be solved... Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for then.  x

```
public class ColorConverter : IDateToBrushConverter
{
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }

    public Brush Convert(DateTime dateTime, bool isSelected, Brush defaultValue, BrushType brushType)
    {
        if (brushType == BrushType.Background)
        {
            if (Dates != null && Dates.Any(d => d == dateTime))
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            }
            return defaultValue;
        }
        if (dateTime == new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 6))
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

}

You can feed dates to the converter in a number of ways.  Here is an example from the page's code behind file

```
        // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dates = new DateTime[]
            {
                new DateTime(2013,9,10),
                new DateTime(2013,9,14),
                new DateTime(2013,9,20),
                new DateTime(2013,9,30),
            };
        ((ColorConverter) Resources["ColorConverter"]).Dates = dates;
    }
```